# Error 404: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting 404 error while running my web application on server... I tried many things but i'm unable to resolve the issue

My controller code is..

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model theModel) {
        return "list-customers";
    }
}
```

my spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml file is as below....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
        <property name="user" value="springstudent" />
        <property name="password" value="springstudent" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>  
    
    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luv2code.springdemo.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ... -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
</beans>
```

my web.xml file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>spring-mvc-crud-demo</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I used the url:
http://localhost:8080/web-customer-tracker/customer/list

My project structure is...
[image]

Kindly help me with this.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: (1) Use Spring Boot unless there's a compelling reason why you can't. (2) Your "all customers" URL should normally just be `/customers` (GET without an ID says "retrieve all"). (3) I _think_ the problem is that you didn't map `/**`, but I haven't used this old style in 7 years because Boot makes it unnecessary.

Comment: Solving your problem now.

Comment: @AnishB. This is the link for the github repo..this repo will have some additional code... which i inserted later... https://github.com/Venkat-juju/Spring-Project

Comment: Thank you :) for providing repo

Comment: @Anish B DId you find any solution?

Comment: @Venkataramanan I was busy with some work yesterday. I will check.

Comment: @Venkataramanan Your project is failing on deployment in tomcat.

Comment: @Ventaramanan You code is now working. Fixed some of the issues.

Comment: I have added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the dynamic project is created in a wrong way.

I have used `tomcat 8.5.57 version` for my testing with `JDK 8`.

I was facing this issue while deploying the project on tomcat :

```
More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering
```

I fixed the **web.xml** with adding `<absolute-ordering/>`.

The project is deployed on tomcat and it's working.

Screenshot :

[image]

My github code : https://github.com/anish-fullstack/web-customer-tracker

Comment: B Thank you very much for your valuable time. But unfortunately it is not working for me. I think there will be some environment issues. Can u please connect with me on linkedin. i have sent u a connection request. Thank you.

Comment: B Thank you so much for your time and support.. :-)